# get cell background color in poi event

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I importing a very large excel with POI event. I got all the contents, but not the cell background color!

I tried the ExtendedFormatRecords (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5415288/retrieving-cell-style-informationspecifically-color-using-poi-event-api)) but i cannot identify which is the previous cell that has the information of row and column numbers!

In my case, I need the color of the NumberRecords!

Here's how i tried:

```
    switch (record.getSid()) {
    case BOFRecord.sid:
        break;
    case BoundSheetRecord.sid:
        BoundSheetRecord bsr = (BoundSheetRecord) record;
        System.out.println("New sheet named: " + bsr.getSheetname());
        break;
    case RowRecord.sid:
        break;
    case NumberRecord.sid: // Contains a numeric cell value
        NumberRecord numrec = (NumberRecord) record;
        row = numrec.getRow();
        col = numrec.getColumn();
        //Do something
        break;
    case ExtendedFormatRecord.sid:
        ExtendedFormatRecord efr = (ExtendedFormatRecord) record;
        if (previousSid == NumberRecord.sid) {
            // row = previousRecord.getRow();
            // col = previousRecord.getColumn();
            // System.out.println("row: " + row + " column: " + col);
            System.out.println("ExtendedFormat "+efr.getFillForeground() + "");
        } else {
            System.out.println("ops! not that");
        }
        break;
        //other cases
        ...
    }//end switch
    previousSid = record.getSid();
    if (previousRecord != record) {
        previousRecord = null;
    }
```

Can anyone help me!?

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11981672/1211000

Comment: @swamy That didn't work because I'm using the [POI Event API](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/how-to.html#event_api) and it doesn't give access to CellStyle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before we get too much into details, I think there are two bits of code you should take a look at. The first is part of Apache POI, and handles tracking formatting and styles when processing an Excel file as part of the EventUserModel - [FormatTrackingHSSFListener](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/java/org/apache/poi/hssf/eventusermodel/FormatTrackingHSSFListener.java). Secondly, part of Apache Tika, is an example of using that to do on-the-fly formatting of cells in event processing - [ExcelExtractor](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tika/trunk/tika-parsers/src/main/java/org/apache/tika/parser/microsoft/ExcelExtractor.java)

What you want to do should be possible, but it'll need a little bit of work. Luckily, the formatting and style information in Excel is part of the workbook information, not part of the sheet information, so it comes first. What you'll need to do is cache those records when you first reach them, so you have them available to use when the cells come past.

Secondly, you should take a look at the POI UserModel code, and see how it actually works with the records to handle the colours and formatting. While you can't use the classes, you can most likely borrow a few key snippets of code from them for your own classes to implement the same sort of thing.

What you'll want to do is use FormatTrackingHSSFListener to get the ExtendedFormatRecords available, and then to look up the record for each cell you come across. On the XFR, you'll find all sorts of colour related details. There are the fill foreground and background colours, the borders and the fonts. Next, when you get the PaletteRecord, keep it, and wrap it in a UserModel HSSFPalette class. You can then use that to get the colours based on the indexes from the XFR. You should also capture the FontRecords, so you can look those up from the index on the XFR, and from the FontRecord you can get a colour index, look that up on HSSFPalette and you're done!

Finally, if you do get it working, please consider sending it in as an enhancement to Apache POI to help the next person!

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked. The trick was to understand that the ExtendedFormatRecord is part of the workbook and how to link it to the cells latter! I couldn't access the HSSFPalete constructor, so a recreated the class with a different name (ExcelPalette) but the same content.

Comment: If anyone else needs it, I changed the previous code to:
`case PaletteRecord.sid: palette = new ExcelPalette((PaletteRecord) record);break;
case ExtendedFormatRecord.sid:
   ExtendedFormatRecord xfr = (ExtendedFormatRecord) record;
   _xfRecords.add(xfr);
   break;
case NumberRecord.sid: // Contains a numeric cell value
   NumberRecord numrec = (NumberRecord) record;
   ExtendedFormatRecord xfr = _xfRecords.get(numrec.getXFIndex());
   if (xfr != null) { 
     HSSFColor color = palette.getColor(xfr.getFillForeground());
     if (color != null) 
       short[] rgb = color.getTriplet();
 ...`